# How do I use emacs diff with spaces?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Given a diff file created using git format-patch (in unified patch format), how do I load that same file in emacs such that I can use C-c C-c to go to the respective location in the file, even if the file or directory name contains a space, on windows.

My project contains a lot of file and directory names that contain spaces.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug? It ought to work, even on Windows.

Comment: Even if it's a bug, there should be a workaround.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error "Can't find the beginning of the file".  Is this what you get?

Comment: Working outside my comfort zone, but does ediff-diff.el work? http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-39/emacs/lisp/ediff-diff.el

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug in Emacs. 
Here is a patch which appears to fix it for me:

```
=== modified file 'lisp/vc/diff-mode.el'
--- lisp/vc/diff-mode.el    2013-01-02 16:13:04 +0000
+++ lisp/vc/diff-mode.el    2013-02-26 05:08:48 +0000
@@ -821,9 +821,11 @@ If the OLD prefix arg is passed, tell th
               (progn (diff-hunk-prev) (point))
             (error (point-min)))))
      (header-files
-      (if (looking-at "[-*][-*][-*] \\(\\S-+\\)\\(\\s-.*\\)?\n[-+][-+][-+] \\(\\S-+\\)")
-          (list (if old (match-string 1) (match-string 3))
-            (if old (match-string 3) (match-string 1)))
+           ;; handle filenames with spaces;
+           ;; cf. diff-font-lock-keywords / diff-file-header-face
+      (if (looking-at "[-*][-*][-*] \\([^\t]+\\)\t.*\n[-+][-+][-+] \\([^\t]+\\)")
+          (list (if old (match-string 1) (match-string 2))
+            (if old (match-string 2) (match-string 1)))
         (forward-line 1) nil)))
       (delq nil
        (append
```

I will commit it to the Emacs bzr source tree if there will be no objections.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, however your patch makes sense, rather than being merely whitespace separated you're not tab-separated where relevant.  I'll consider adding a bounty to it when I've been able to test it. :)